# Security for cross-origin resource sharing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, cors

I have 2 ruby on rails app sitting on 2 different domains (say *`www.exampleA.com`* and *`www.exampleB.com`*. I want to share resources between the 2 apps and I'm using CORS:

*`exampleA.com`* sends http POST request to *`exampleB.com`*.

At *`exampleB.com`* I'm checking `request.env['HTTP_ORIGIN']` to make sure that the request comes from *`exampleA.com`*. If true I respond by setting the response headers to allow the http post request.

My question is can I use `request.env['HTTP_ORIGIN']` as the only check to verify the identity of requester?

Is it possible for someone from *`www.exampleC.com`* to fake their HTTP_ORIGIN to look like *`www.exampleA.com`* and post malicious data? If so what's the best way to verify requester identity?

Comment: Never, ever trust anything from a client. A client can fake anything they send to the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Origin*](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#origin-request-header) is one of several [header fields that cannot be set for a XHR request by page authors](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader-method). So you’re safe to trust the *Origin* information of XHR requests.

But it is still possible for an attacker to send forged requests with malicious data directly. So you’re still required to validate incoming requests.

Comment: "Safe" is relative. Consider if someone *was* able to send any data they they liked (such as from a malicious native application, vuln in Flash or Java, or so on), and if that would expose you to security risk or them execute actions on your behalf

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but it is trivially easy to fake most client-provided data, origin included, and hence it should not be used for any type of security.

Comment: However this is client-side anyway and the OP is enabling a client-side mechanism (CORS) so if the client faked a referer they are only reducing _their own protection_.

Comment: @SilverlightFox - from op "Is it possible for someone from www.exampleC.com to fake their HTTP_ORIGIN to look like www.exampleA.com and post malicious data?"

Comment: Yes they could make a request directly, but not one that also includes the victim's auth cookie on the client side.

Comment: I'm not making any assumptions.

Comment: Where in the OP does it say "auth cookie", then? I'm done discussing this with you. If you require further clarification, present it as a question so it can be handled by people that care a lot more than I do right now...

Comment: I commented to inform in case anyone else comes across your answer, not to argue. After all, this is what SO is about. First point is that you're commenting on the `referer` header, the OP mentions the `Origin` header - this is different. If you are saying not to trust the `Origin` header then you are essentially saying not to use CORS at all as it is insecure. The `Origin` header is what everything hinges on within [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/). Making a request from a browser is different than making a pure HTTP request because the DOM is at stake here.