# Best security practices for React + Django

Tags: django, reactjs, security, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I'm currently working on a project that uses Django API server and a NodeJS server running React. In development we're running Django on port 8000 and NodeJS on port 8080, and currently React is responsible for rendering the page and interacting with Django API, which provides data for React. In order for React to call Django APIs, we've enabled CORS in Django since they're on different ports.

My question is the following:

1. Is it safe to allow all CORS in production?
2. If not using the templates system by Django, is the site still protected against CSRF by defaults? If not, how to prevent CSRF in such settings (React+Django)?

Comment: How does the API authenticate users? This is a key question wrt CSRF. Ie. is there a Bearer token, or a session id in a cookie, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, it's safe to use CORS in production if you allow it for the correct origin domains. For example, if you are using [`django-cors-headers`](https://github.com/OttoYiu/django-cors-headers), use CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=False and a set of domains for `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST`.
2. As the [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30871033/django-rest-framework-remove-csrf) explain, DRF uses CSRF tokens if using `SessionAuthentication`. However, if you are using other authentication mechanism (for example, token authentication or JWT) you are however also protected by the client browser not allowing unsecure requests from untrusted origins, i.e. not in your `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST`. See [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680302/csrf-protection-with-cors-origin-header-vs-csrf-token#24692474) regarding security of CORS vs. CSRF token to prevent CSRF in general.