# Cross Site Request Forgery protection with Django and websockets

Tags: django, csrf, django-channels

I've successfully created a websocket on my Django(v. 2.0)-powered website using Django channels (v. 2.1.5).

Everything is fine but I'm wondering what about CSRF token. Is it needed in case of websockets? [Documentation](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/security.html) says that it's enough to use `OriginValidator` to prevent such thread but I'd like to ensure that. I mean, what has happend to CSRF token? Am I just sending data through secure channel without it and backend automagically checks everything? And if that's so then why? And why simple views can't do that?

I know it's preety open question but I was not able to find any specific explanation, if anyone has one I'd more than greatful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CSRF token are not required when you are using websocket connections.

When you visit a malicious website, it could send a post-request via javascript to another website, where you are currently logged in. Your browser would also send you session-cookie to this other website, so the webserver thinks that you did willingly send this post-request and would execute the request. The CSRF-cookie prevents this. Thins the malicious site can not read the value of the CSRF-cookie, it can not add the value to the post-request.

It is also possible for a malicious website to open a websocket connection to a different site. That is the reason, why you have to use a OriginValidator. If you use it, then the server accepts only websocket connections from *your* site.

When the malicious site tries to open a connection to your server, it gets rejected right away.

So the difference between a post-request and a websocket-connections is, that browsers sent a origin header on websocket connections but not always on post requests.

It seems that modern browsers always send the origin header: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin

So maybe you don't have to use the CSRF-cookie at all. See also: [CSRF protection with CORS Origin header vs. CSRF token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680302/csrf-protection-with-cors-origin-header-vs-csrf-token)